# How to implement wallet connection with Ethers.js v6 for multiple providers (MetaMask, Coinbase)

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, wallets, react, web3-providers

I'm building a DApp and want to provide wallet connection options for users. I'm using Ethers.js v6 for Ethereum interactions. My goal is to allow users to click buttons like "Connect to MetaMask" or "Connect to Coinbase wallet" and open the corresponding wallet.

[image]
[image]

If a selected provider is unavailable, I'd like to show an error message recommending an alternative provider.

I followed the [Ethers.js getting started docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/getting-started/#starting-connecting) and adjusted the snippet they provided for handling multiple providers. Here's my code:

```
export const getProvider = (wallet: AllowedWalletType) => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.ethereum) {
    const { providers } = window.ethereum;

    const supportedProviders: WalletProviders = {
      coinbase: providers.find((p) => p.isCoinbaseWallet),
      metamask: providers.find((p) => p.isMetaMask),
    };

    const selectedProvider = supportedProviders[wallet];
    return new ethers.BrowserProvider(selectedProvider);
  } else {
    // Read only provider. Useful for the user end app.
    return ethers.getDefaultProvider({
      chainId: parseInt(SEPOLIA_NETWORK_ID),
    });
  }
};
```

The code above successfully connects to the different wallets, but I can't access the browser Ethereum events **(e.g., window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", ...))**. However, if I use **return new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)** instead of **return new ethers.BrowserProvider(selectedProvider)**, I can access events, but the wallet connections don't work as expected (both MetaMask and Coinbase prompt an intermediate window that I don't like to show to the users).

[image]

Also an error that keeps repeating in the console every 1s

```
JsonRpcProvider failed to detect network and cannot start up; retry in 1s (perhaps the URL is wrong or the node is not started)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I implement wallet connections for both MetaMask and Coinbase while preserving event access?